# How do i can run directive function before controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need call directive function ( i need scope ) before controller.

```
var app = angular.module('docsRestrictDirective', []);

app.controller('Controller', ['$scope',  function($scope ) {
  $scope.changeDerictive();
}]);

app.directive('ngMyDer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      return {
        pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
          scope.changeDerictive = function() {

            console.log("changed");
          };
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/NWb23rScg8zvPluGBWH5?p=preview

Comment: Not possible. Directives live inside controllers, not the other way around. A directive's `$scope` is a child of the controller's `$scope` which itself is a child of `$rootScope`.

Comment: @cyber_ua you could share us an idea.. we could find a better way to do this\

Comment: @PankajParkar I changed example in question. I known only one solution it is setTimeout ( ..., 0)

Comment: Another solution http://plnkr.co/edit/CxIWJmLqRCGw4UU2NJ5F?p=preview but he very confused

Comment: some sort of base controller would be what you would need

Comment: @Jony-Y How can i do it?

Comment: well if you use ui-router its fairly simple, you define a base controller in the routes  by adding the abstract value to it. and your controller will run after it loads, in the base controller you define all of your base initializations, then you run the directive before the ui-view in the base controller so the directive actually loads before your controller and after the directive you run the ui-view... also you can just define a base controller in the html and then the directive then ui-view and then all paths will run after the directive

Comment: if this is what you were referring to and you need an example Ill post a snippet

Comment: @Jony-Y Make please an example

Comment: what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Saying "I need this to run first, because I need `$scope`" sounds too much like an XY problem to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as requested this is the example with ui-router.
first we will define a controller for the base of the app.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppBaseCtrl">
    <main role="main">
        <overlay-spinner></overlay-spinner>
        <invite-success></invite-success>
        <div ui-view></div>
    </main>
</body>
```

now in the ui router we will define our base route:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/desiredRoute');
        $stateProvider
            .state('desiredRoute', {
                url: '/desiredRoute',
                templateUrl: 'views/pathToTemplate.html',
                controller: 'MyViewCtrl'
            })
});
```

so what will happen? the base controller runs, we can initialize desired scope variables, then we run the directives and then we run our required controller.

so you have the directive which runs before the needed controller.

if we want this to be cleaner with ui-router we can define the routes like this:

in the routes config:

```
  .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'views/templates/dashboard/dashboard-base.html',
        controller: 'DashboardBaseCtrl',
        abstract: true
    })
    .state('dashboard.main', {
        url: '/main',
        templateUrl: 'views/templates/dashboard/dashboard-main.html',
        controller: 'DashboardMainCtrl'
    })
```

then in the view for the dashboard-base:

```
<div myDirective></div>
<div ui-view></div>
```

and of course define in the base controller what ever you want and as you can see... base controller runs then directive then our desired controller so directive runs before the controller...

**EDIT**

I have created a small plunker like you asked... you will see here that with no timeout the directive is called before our main controller does using a base controller my example is the first example in the answer

[plunker with answer](http://plnkr.co/edit/YZbmdnZDAC1Ssf6KQyDg?p=preview)

Comment: I not understood you, sorry. 
I have two elements on page they have directive ng-exchange="id"
after call exchangeElements in controller need change their position,
very easy example on jquery http://jsfiddle.net/4tvpm50s/

Comment: so if I understood what you're saying, you need to define the two directives in the base controller html, then in the base controller have the exchange function. then from the controller you can do what you need to do to trigger the directives either by changing the $parent.id or something and they will call the exchange function from the parent controller... since they are all under the base controller they all have access to the same scope.

Comment: Example http://plnkr.co/edit/fagINqNafPp6vEhawNbl?p=preview, how can i make this without setTimeout(..., 0 ) ?

Comment: check out my edit, I have created an example with plunker

Comment: Thank you very much, after your example understood it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your ng-controller is written before your directive ,so if you want to call directive frist write ng-controller after your directive
like this

```
  <body ng-app="docsRestrictDirective">
      <div ></div>
       <div  ng-my-der></div>
    <div ng-controller="Controller"></div>
    </body>
```

Then it will show result according to you

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/0qccTyPADwDaq05KKmao?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

There is a priority between angularjs directives.**`ng-controller`** **is directive too**,try that priority.Maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers.
I did it this way

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller( "Ctrl",[ "$scope", function ( $scope ) {

   $scope.$watch ( "ngExchange", function ( ) {
     $scope._ngExchange[0].remove()
     $scope._ngExchange[1].after( $scope._ngExchange[0] );

   } );


} ] );

app.directive('ngExchange', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      controller: function ( $scope, $element, $attrs ) {

        if ( $scope._ngExchange === undefined ) {
          $scope._ngExchange = [];
        }

        $scope._ngExchange.push( $element );


      }
    }

});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/fagINqNafPp6vEhawNbl?p=preview